# How to Capture control codes in pexpect python module

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pexpect

I am running some commands in pexpect session where it gives the following output in console.

```
this is the first line output
\u0000>\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

I am having a regex '\r\n>' to match the prompt '>' at the new line.
From the output I can see there is one control character \u0000 is prefixed before the prompt comes

```
\u0000>\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

My code goes like

```
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
child.sendline(command)
child.expect('\r\n>')
```

Because of this control character prefixed before the prompt, the expect is failing. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Logically we can see the prompt came in next line, but literally how we can match along with control character?

Do i need to modify my regex to match **"controlchar\r\n>"**? or any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Try `'\r\n\\u0000?>'`. It should match linebreak, an optional NULL char and `>`

Comment: Yes, but this is hardcoding for only \u0000 character, what if someother control characters appears?
I have a regex '\r\n(\\u\d+)*>' but I want more robus solution. like what if the control code starts with some other instead of \u
Is there any possibility I can get list of control characters and their meanings?

Comment: See https://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm